# get_terms vs. get_categories: does it matter?

Tags: categories, terms

I'm fairly new to wordpress and am coming across new things each day - one was today when I happened across `get_terms` and noticed that it was basically the same as `get_category`.

Any particular reason to use one or the other? Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you dive into WordPress, you'll find that WordPress has a lot of wrapper functions. For instance, there's `add_theme_page` that's just a wrapper of `add_submenu_page`. That's certainly not the only example (`add_submenu_page` itself has a bunch of wrappers, in fact). If you look at [the source for `get_categories()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/category.php#L39), you'll see that it too is a wrapper for `get_terms()` (I just learned that myself, so thanks!).

I find that the taxonomy-related functions are some of the most convoluted. A lot of them take very similar arguments and return similar things with little differences. In this case, `get_terms()` has a `name__like` parameter that `get_category()` doesn't. There are probably other little differences too.

As a personal preference, I try to use `get_terms()` as much as possible. In some cases, like `add_theme_page` that's the recommended function (presumably so WordPress could make changes to the Theme page and keep that function working), but in other cases like this one, I don't think it makes much of a difference. If nothing else, the familiarity helps me do more with it faster. However, some of the functions that return HTML lists like `wp_list_categories()` can be useful at times.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important (and not very obvious) differences between **get_terms()** and **get_categories()** is that **get_categories()** is a wrapper function for **get_terms('category')**.  This means that you *cannot* get custom taxonomies with **get_categories()** and must use **get_terms()** instead.

Comment: Doh, this may not be true.  Please disregard until I get an opportunity to verify a previous issue I ran in to.  My apologies.

Comment: Did you see the accepted answer that already explains this?

Comment: @BrentClark Did you ever find out if this was true? It's a more helpful answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to query custom taxonomy with `get_categories`

example:

```php
// Taxonomy query
$venue_args = array(
  'child_of'   => $venue_id,
  'taxonomy'   => 'wpmf-category',
  'hide_empty' => false
);
$venue_cats = get_categories( $venue_args );
```