# Get Categories Where Taxonomy Equals 'n'

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy(the taxonomy is *types*) that is basically a selector that tells WordPress which section of the site to place the new post.

So for example

1. I create a new post and select **Lifestyle**  from the custom taxonomy list.
2. Then I would select a category to place the post under, for example **Healthy**

I am trying to list the categories of **Lifestyle** in a custom menu format but only if posts exist under the taxonomy type and category selected.

What I am getting is a full list of categories but not filtered by taxonomy type.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'types' => 'Lifestyle',
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty' => 1
  );
$categories=get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->count > 0){
    echo '<li class="'.$category->slug.'"><a href="?category=' . $category->slug . '">'.$category->name.' / '.$category->count.'</a></li>';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Thanks so much in advnce!
-d

Answer (score 2):

`get_categories()` only lists categories, so you shouldn't be seeing any terms from the custom taxonomy. What you want to use is `get_terms()` which takes a taxonomy as an argument. As you can read about in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53223/get-terms-vs-get-categories-does-it-matter/53224#53224), `get_terms()` is actually used by `get_categories()`, it just prefills the "taxonomy" argument with "category."

If you swap in `get_terms()` and add the name of your custom taxonomy, your code looks like it should work. The only other thing you may be able to change is your `if` statement checking the category count. If you're already doing `'hide_empty' => 1` you shouldn't need that.